# Xcode , Parse - Storing values from an array object in a local array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I want the user to upload an image, and other users leave replies to that image, everything works fine so fat except i can't get save the replies inside the "replies" object/column in Parse into my local array in order to display them. it can't accept the : `for in` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


        var query = PFQuery(className:"Posts")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(cellID) {
            (objects: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                println(objects["replies"])

                self.repliesArray.append(objects["replies"] as String) // <- problem Here

            } else {

                println("Error retreiving")
                self.displayError("Error", error: "Error retrieving")

            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the replies column is a string, try this:

```
if error == nil {
    var array = objects.objectForKey("replies") as [String]
    for obj in array {
        self.repliesArray.append(obj as String)
    }
}
```

Comment: error : 'PFObject' does not have a member called 'count'

Comment: What is the type of column "replies"?

Comment: Array, i can post to it perfectly.

Comment: An array of what? Strings? If so, try the new code.

Comment: gave me an error so i did this : " for object in  array {
                    self.repliesArray.append(object as String)}"
But you sure helped me get there, so thank you.

Comment: problem now is if the row for specific object is already empty.Will have to write several lines of code to solve that.

Comment: Create another question and link it here so we don't fill up the comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186866/xcode-parse-retrieving-values-from-an-empty-array