# Retrieving values from an empty array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I want the user to upload an image, and other users leave replies to that image. Everything works fine so far except if the row for that specific image object is empty, the app crashes.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var error = ""

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Posts")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(cellID) {
        (objects: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {      
            var array = objects.objectForKey("replies") as [String] // <- when error occurs the compiler point here.
            for object in  array {
                self.repliesArray.append(object as String)
            }
        } else { 
            self.displayError("Error", error: "Error retreiving")
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? You can't append null objects to an array so this appends an empty string instead of null. Also you need the explanation mark so that it can be nil.

```
var array = objects.objectForKey("replies") as [String!]
for object in array {
    if object != nil {
        self.repliesArray.append(object as String)
    }
    else {
        self.repliesArray.append("")
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives ann error, tried so many different If statements but kept giving me same error.

Comment: Error: Type 'NSString' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

Answer (score 0):

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(cellID) {
    (objects: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {      
        var array = objects.objectForKey("replies") as [String] // <- when error occurs the compiler point here.
```

The key here is that you're accepting an implicitly unwrapped optional (`PFObject!`) which is implying a promise that it will never be `nil`, but is `nil`.

Ideally (*), the type should be `(objects: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void` to make the optionals explicit and force you to do the `nil` checking that is required. I believe you can do this even if the caller claims to send you `(PFObject!, NSError!) -> Void`, since I think Swift will make the implicit->explicit conversion for you.

If that's still impossible, then you will have to manually verify that `objects` is not `nil` before using it. (This is unlike @Dehli's solution, which checks that the things *contained* in `objects` are non-`nil`. That's not the problem; the problem is that `objects` itself is `nil`.)

(*) I say "ideally" here in terms of the existing interface. Passing a tuple of optional value/error is a lousy pattern. The better solution is to use something like a [`Result` object](https://github.com/LlamaKit/LlamaKit/blob/master/LlamaKit/Result.swift).